# Using an html button to call a Javascript function that loads a specific image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

```
<html>
<body>
  <br/>
   <script>
        var i = 1;
        var pag="p"+String(i)+".svg";

        function pageno(param)
        {             
            i=param;
            pag="p"+param+".svg";
            document.getElementById('slide').src=pag;
        }

        </script>

<div>
    <iframe src="p1.svg" id="slide" height=900 width=1105 allowTransparency="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" >
    </iframe>
      <form >
        Page:
        <input type="text" name="pg">
        <input id="submit" type="button" value="submit" onclick="pageno('pg')" >

    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This script was for loading a specific image file with extension `.svg` using a 
 textbox to take input of the page number and load the image file with name:

```
"p"+pgno+".svg"
```

But the call to the function `pageno` with parameter as `pg` isn't working.I tried looking at similar problems but the solutions didn't work for me.

Is there a better way to do this?

**The html file is in the same location as of the images(.svg)**

***So can anyone help me on why the images aren't loading ?***

Comment: well `pg` is not defined anywhere ... also, a submit button loads a new page

Comment: Well my bad for pg but the submit button also didnt work for me

Comment: yes, well, submit loads a new page

Comment: @JaromandaX                                                                                       
         `<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="pageno('pg')" >`                   shouldnt it be the required line then?

Comment: submit in a form loads a new page

Comment: @JaromandaX So it cant be helped?

Comment: yes it can, return false or event.preventDefault() are two common ways

Comment: where can i add it?

Comment: well, if the accepted answer works, then you obviously don't need it, I must be wrong

Comment: @JaromandaX You are right, just tell where can i add that to make the new image load instead of page refresh.

Comment: `onclick="pageno('pg'); return false"` may be enough

Comment: can you move this discussion to chat?

Comment: Don't have the time for discussion

Comment: But now the picture wont load only the button and textbox is seen.The default picture is also gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this help you, I'm answering you question in jquery because you have the question tagged as Jquery.

In my answer I've some code lines commented un-comment them and remove the line below those commented lines.

Also like to mention that to remove the default action from a button just change the type as follows.

`<input type="button" >`

this makes the button to be just a button

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#submit', function() {
    var i = 1,
      pageNo = $('#pg').val(),
      //img = "p" + i + ".svg";
      img = "https://static.pexels.com/photos/55787/pexels-photo-55787.jpeg";//Remove this line and uncomment the line above this

    if (pageNo !== "") {
      //img = "p" + pageNo + ".svg";
      img = pageNo; //remove this when you're using this code coppy pate a URL to the text area to see it getting loaded to the iframe.
      $('#slide').prop('src', img);
    }else{
     $('#slide').prop('src', img);
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Page:
  <input type="text" id="pg">
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit">
  <iframe src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/17679/pexels-photo.jpg" id="slide" height=900 width=1105 allowTransparency="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0">
  </iframe>
</form>
```

Also you here is a corking [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sadaruwan12/5domzm3a/3/). Please test this and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Can you move to the chat please

Answer (score 0):

`Submit` button is working fine. Please check for other errors

```js
function pageno(pg) {
  alert(pg)
}
```

```html
<form >
        Page:
        <input type="text" name="pg">
        <input id="submit" type="button" value="submit"         onclick="pageno('pg')" >

</form>
```

Comment: I actually need a place to preventDefault() for submit button

Comment: @Amar30657 if this didn't solve your problem it's better not to mark it as the best answer you can only select one answer as the best answer.